# spring boot app immediately shut down after started

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I added a logger that time; it was working fine. After that I added email functionality, then it gave me an error. I have removed all dependency and commented all email functionality code. Even then it is not working.

```plaintext
      ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.2)

2022-04-24 14:38:04 - o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-9090"]
2022-04-24 14:38:04 - o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-04-24 14:38:04 - o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.56]
2022-04-24 14:38:04 - o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-04-24 14:38:04 - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-04-24 14:38:05 - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-04-24 14:38:06 - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-04-24 14:38:06 - com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-04-24 14:38:06 - o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>shopaxAPI</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>shopaxAPI</name>
    <description>use for manage product </description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>/shopaxAPI/src/main/java/com/shopaxAPI/ShopaxApiApplication.java</start-class>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>


        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId> <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId> 
            <version>1.6.2</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId> <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId> 
            <version>2.3.28</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId> 
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId> <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId> 
            <version>3.12.0</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>commons-io</groupId> <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId> 
            <version>2.11.0</version> </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.auth0/java-jwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty -->
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId> <artifactId>jetty</artifactId> 
            <version>7.0.0.pre5</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
            <exclusions> <exclusion> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```properties
#logDir=/Users/apple/Desktop/tomcat/ 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopax
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=100MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=100MB
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
server.port=9090
logging.config=classpath:logback.xml
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.guru.springframework.controllers=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.file.path=logs/spring-boot-logging.log


#hello
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
```

Comment: What does your own code actually do?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re creating a web application, then add the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency, this will keep the application running.

```
    <dependency>    
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>  
    </dependency>
```

Comment: i was using logger so error was not being displayed at console then i checked log file then i got the error log the issue was i was using email service with autowired and that bean does not have bean annotation..by the way thanks @MevlütÖzdemir